# solving a differential equation perhaps with some software

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

i have been struggling to find a free program that can solve this equation as i cannot do it myself, can anyone recommend a program i could download from the internet or better yet, show me how to solve this? all terms other that f(t) are constants. 
thanks for any answers

$$f(t)=\frac{zd}{R^3}f'(t)\left(\int \int (V-f(t))^2dt\right)+\frac{V-f(t)}{R^3D}kz\int (V-f(t))^2dt$$

---

[This is the equation i need to solve for f(t)](http://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=f(t)=%5Cfrac%7Bzd%7D%7BR%5E3%7Df'(t)*(%5Cint&space;%5Cint&space;(V-f(t))%5E2dt)+%5Cfrac%7BV-f(t)%7D%7BR%5E3D%7Dkz%5Cint&space;(V-f(t))%5E2dt%22%20target=%22_blank%22%3E%3Cimg)

Comment: I can almost guarantee that equation cannot be solved analytically - you will have to do it numerically.

Comment: @lovsovs  hello, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Hi! I mean that you probably cannot expect to find $f(t)$ in terms of "nice" functions, like $e^t,\sin t,t^3$, etc.

Comment: @lovsovs ok, even so, i do not know how to solve this, can the laplace transform apply?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: What does the double integral mean (there is only one variable t). What is the range of integration or is it indefinite integration?

Comment: @Paul Integral is indefinite, constant always 0 for that specific function and double integral means integrate that function twice both times with regards to dt. Sorry about the notation mistakes